# Is it true that you do not lose ANY muscle mass if you're in a conservative deficit, eat high protein and do resistance training?

Tags: muscle, strength, diet, protein, cutting

We are talking about people who are novices or early intermediates. There's no question that if you are advanced (i.e you are close to your genetic potential), you **will** lose muscle unless you take juice of course.

I have read on many blogs that whenever you are in a cutting phase, you will lose muslce no matter what your training experience is. Many coaches say otherwise. They say that people who eat enough protein (1gm/lb), are in a moderate caloric deficit (20-25%) and do resistance training 3 - 5 times per week **gain** muscle even when in a deficit if the trainee is a novice or an early intermediate.

Which one of these claims is true?

Comment: You also have to factor in the amount of time you stay at the deficit, and the body fat % you're at. I went from 22 to 10% BF and gained a few kg of lean mass (some of it muscle) on a deficit in my first year as a beginner. I don't think the result would be the same if I started at 10%.